# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}^1_R$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, affine-geometry, affine-schemes, automorphism-group

When $R$ is an integral domain, the automorphisms of the affine line are all of the form $X \mapsto aX + b$ with $a \in R^\times$ and $b \in R$; the proof is the same as in the case of $R$ a field, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252773/196668). It is easy to see that this group of maps is isomorphic to the semidirect product $R^\times \! \rtimes R^+$.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0973.pdf) by Dupuy studies the case where $R$ is not reduced. In particular, he proves that the group 
$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}/m})$ is solvable, for *arbitrary* m. What other properties does it have? Is there an explicit description of this group?

For example, with a bit of playing around I found that $\varphi(X) = X + 2X^2$ is an involutive automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/4)[X]$: 
$$\varphi^2(X) = (X + 2X^2) + 2(X + 2X)^2 = X + 4X^2 + 4X^3 + 8X^4$$
which reduces to $X$ when we take the coefficients mod 4. But I could not generalize this example to the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^2$.

Also, what can be said in the case that $R$ is reduced but not integral? E.g. $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY)$ or $\mathbb{Z}/6$.

Comment: @user1952009 Your homomorphism $\phi(X \mapsto aX + b) = a$ is not defined on all of $\text{Aff}(R)$ because there are, in general, more elements in there than just maps of the form $aX + b$.

Comment: So you meant $Aut(R[x])$. If your ring $R = S/I$ is the quotient of an integral domain then we can search for polynomials $U,V = x+x^2 v(x) \in S[X]$ such that $U(V(x))-x \in I$, in that case $U = V^{-1}$ in $Aut(R[x])$. What does it mean about $I$ ?

Comment: Automorphisms of the affine line correspond to automorphisms of $R[X]$, that is, pairs of polynomials $(P,Q)$ with $Q\circ P = X$. When $R$ is reduced, one can show that $P$ has to be "in" $R^\times \rtimes R^+$